# Azure DevOps API - change WorkItemType for test cases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In our Azure DevOps environment we have two projects.
An older project, that has test cases that were created previously.
A new project where new test cases are being created. This project is using a new process, that has a modified "Test Case" Work Item Type.

We wanted to clone the "old" cases to the new project and used the API to do it.
Test cases were cloned successfully, the only issue we have is that cloned test cases are not the same "Test Case" work item type and are missing some additional fields, that the newly created test cases have.

So far, I did not manage to find any solution on how to reapply/change the new work item type for the cloned test cases.

The API used was "Clone Test Suite" (destinationWorkItemType was included).

Anyone struggled with something similar maybe ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share how the new field in the modified test case work time type is defined? I tested with the "Clone Test Suite" API, the customized fields appear on the cloned test cases as expected.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, the new field is added under the summary tab in the "Test case" WIT. In your case, are the source and destination project using a different process ?

Comment: No, they are using different inherited processes. they both inherit from the same agile process